# Not a single PHP file is recognized as PHP file in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, phpstorm

I really don't know what could cause such a strange behavior from mentioned editor. Literally all project files with `.php` extension are recognized as... text files I suppose. I know that stuff like that happens when the extension is forgotten during making of a PHP class for example, but I cannot explain why this appended to all files in the project.

I know that I can change file type of each individual class, but I'm doing a Laravel project and I can't manually change file type of every single default PHP class each time when I start a new project and each time I myself add a new class.

Is there any setting which defines rules for certain file types, since changing file types of every individual project file isn't a solution? At least, not viable one.

[image]

Comment: Try opening `File > Settings` and searching for `File Types`. There should be a list of `Registered Patterns`, ensure that `*.php` is in that list.

Comment: D1_1, you may like to post that comment as an answer since it solved my problem! The issue was that php was actually recognized as a filetype but .php extension was not. All the files that were associated with PHP format were .hphp, .module, .php4, .php5, .phtml and .inc but not .php for some reason. When I added .php as a new file extension to php file type, it prompted me with a message that .php was attached to text format for some reason. So, I overrode it. After that everything seems to be back to normal. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every language is associated with one or more file extension patterns within the IDE.

Open `File > Settings` and then search for `File Types` and look for `PHP` in this case. There will be a list of `Registered Patterns` associated with PHP.

Ensure that `*.php` is in that list, or add it if it is missing.